# Is There A Way to Determine if More Than One Option in Custom Dropdown Field?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, javascript, jquery, spservices

I have a custom dropdown choice field that is created using jQuery after a date is selected and a choice box is selected as "Yes." Here is that function:

```
    function queryEvents(date){
        $('#events').empty();
        $('#events').append(
            '<option value="N/A">N/A</option>'
        );
        var newDate = new Date();
        var plusSevenDate = new Date(date);
        var minusSevenDate = new Date(date);        

        plusSevenDate.setDate(plusSevenDate.getDate()+7);
        minusSevenDate.setDate(minusSevenDate.getDate()-7);

        plusSevenDays = plusSevenDate.toISOString().split("T")[0];
        minusSevenDays = minusSevenDate.toISOString().split("T")[0];

        CamlQuery = "<Query>" +
                    "<Where>" +
                        "<And>" +
                            "<Gt><FieldRef Name='StartDate' /><Value Type='DateTime'>" + minusSevenDays + "</Value></Gt>" +
                            "<Lt><FieldRef Name='StartDate' /><Value Type='DateTime'>" + plusSevenDays + "</Value></Lt>" +
                        "</And>" +
                    "</Where>" +
                "</Query>" ;
        $().SPServices({
            operation: "GetListItems",
            webURL: "/admin/",
            async: false,
            listName: "Calendar",
            CAMLQuery: CamlQuery,
            CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ID'/><FieldRef Name='LinkTitle'/><FieldRef Name='StartDate'/></ViewFields>",
            completefunc: function (xData, Status) {    
                $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
                    var valueString = $(this).attr("ows_ID") + ';#' + $(this).attr("ows_LinkTitle");
                    $('#events').append(
                        '<option value="' + valueString + '">' + $(this).attr("ows_LinkTitle") + '</option>'
                    );      
                    $('#events').addClass("eventCSS");
                }); //end xml function
            } //end completefunc
    }); //end spservices    
}
```

I need to be able to create an if statement that translates to "if this events option drop down contains more than just the default 'N/A' then show the field" but no matter what I've tried, it just keeps telling me that it contains only one option (when I know for a fact there are more than 10). Here's what I have right now for when that Yes or No field changes (onchange):

```
         $('#ctl00_m_g_420b1f4d_1ab4_4265_99be_345a7b9015f2_ff171_ctl00_DropDownChoice').on('change', function(){
            var choice = this.value; 
            var eventName = $('#events').val();
            var eventDD = $('#events');

            if(choice == 'Yes'){
                //when yes, the event choices will not appear unless there is a value to display    
                if(eventDD.find('option').length > 1){
                    $('.eventField').show(); 
                    var date = $('#ctl00_m_g_420b1f4d_1ab4_4265_99be_345a7b9015f2_ff31_ctl00_ctl00_DateTimeField_DateTimeFieldDate').val();
                    //function filters events based on "Start Date" provided and "Yes" for event-related. Seven days before and seven after.
                    queryEvents(date);
                    //sets the value of sharepoint event field to the currently populated event when Yes is chosen
                    //this exists in case the event the user is looking for does not require them to search and select (first choice)
                    $('#ctl00_m_g_420b1f4d_1ab4_4265_99be_345a7b9015f2_ff141_ctl00_ctl00_TextField').val(eventName);
                    var eventID = eventName.split(';#')[0];
                    $('#ctl00_m_g_420b1f4d_1ab4_4265_99be_345a7b9015f2_ff381_ctl00_ctl00_TextField').val(eventID);
                }
                //if there's no value in the events, show the "no event" error message
                else{

                    $('.eventField').hide();
                    $('.noEvent').show();
                }
            }
            else{
            //if not event related, all default values returned to blank and events/no event messages are hidden
                $('.eventField').hide();
                $('#events').val(''); //sets list value back to blank
                $('#ctl00_m_g_420b1f4d_1ab4_4265_99be_345a7b9015f2_ff141_ctl00_ctl00_TextField').val(''); //sets sharepoint event field to blank
                $('#ctl00_m_g_420b1f4d_1ab4_4265_99be_345a7b9015f2_ff381_ctl00_ctl00_TextField').val('');
                $('.noEvent').hide();
            }
        });
```

Does anyone see something I did wrong here? Or is there another way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting id using jquery selector

For example To get those that end with "ckbxEmp"

```
$(document).on("change", "[id$='ckbxEmp']", function () {
```

Comment: I don't think I quite understand what you're asking me to do, but all values are unique in the options.

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking how many options are in #events before you add them (in queryEvents)?

Comment: I know for a fact there are 8 events listed.